# How could I create a bot that transfer files from FTP to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm on a mission to make a script that will transfer all files from FTP to Google Cloud Storage

I would like to know what tools I could use to create it, or if there is already a script that does this?

I also have the question that the script would have to download each file from FTP and then upload it to Google Cloud Storage? Could the files be uploaded directly from FTP to Google Cloud Storage without having to download and upload them again?

Comment: You have to investigate and come with specific questions about any code you may have. We're not going go to provide or suggest any code, tool or anything nor how you should do it. This is something you should do. Go, investigate then comeback with something very specific related to the code you're doing. For now I'm voting to close this question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the documentation and links I could suggest in order to transfer from FTP to Google Cloud Storage:

- [FTP](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/ftp/configure)

  - This would let you connect to an FTP server and perform file transfer operations

The only [downside](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/ftp/configure#system-limitations) of this is it can only process 1 transaction per second, per [node](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/pricing#payg), and [throttles](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/rate-limiting) any other transactions beyond this limit.

- You may also check the following Stack Overflow links wherein you can use Compute Engine/VM to deploy an FTP server:

  - [FTP to Google Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage)
  - [Set up FTP in Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964361/set-up-ftp-in-google-cloud-platform)

> I also have the question that the script would have to download each file from FTP and then upload it to Google Cloud Storage? Could the files be uploaded directly from FTP to Google Cloud Storage without having to download and upload them again?

It would be better to check out the documentation first as those have options to mount the FTP server into a local filesystem or you could try out [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads).

In addition, you could also check out this [Google Cloud community question](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Integration-Services/Application-Integration-FTP-and-GCS-Connector/m-p/535877) as this could provide additional help in creating your project.